# IO#read blocks on non-blocking socket?

Tags: ruby, sockets, nonblocking

Ruby 1.8.7. I'm calling read on a socket which has been opened and connected with:

```
socket = Socket.new(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)
sockaddr = Socket.sockaddr_in(mp.port, mp.ip_address.ip)
begin
  socket.connect_nonblock(sockaddr)
[...]
```

The connection is confirmed by calling select() and then connecting a second time looking for Errno::EISCONN.

I then call select again with a 0 timeout and if the return is not nil I read from the socket, first confirming that it has O_NONBLOCK set:

```
 rc = select([socket], nil, nil, 0)
 puts "  select returned: #{rc.pretty_inspect}"
 if rc
   begin
     puts "  reading: #{socket} nonblock: #{socket.fcntl(Fcntl::F_GETFL) & Fcntl::O_NONBLOCK}"
     response = socket.read
     puts "  done reading"
     [...]
```

This all happens in a loop once per minute. The output the first time through the loop is:

```
select returned: [[#<Socket:0xb6e0dcb8>], [], []]
reading: #<Socket:0xb6e0dcb8> nonblock: 2048
done reading
```

However the second time through the loop hangs here:

```
select returned: [[#<Socket:0xb6e0dcb8>], [], []]
reading: #<Socket:0xb6e0dcb8> nonblock: 2048
```

Attaching gdb to the process shows this backtrace:

0  0xffffe410 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
1  0xb7e5539d in select () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
2  0x08064368 in rb_thread_schedule () at eval.c:11020
3  0x080785bb in io_fread (

Replacing the call to read with a call to rcvfrom_nonblock works, and interestingly it does not get EAGAIN, it actually reads data (as you would expect given the return from select).

Comment: I don't see in your code where the `mp` is set after the `select(2)`. Are you sure it's indexing to the same socket that's been signaled readable?

Comment: Sorry that's an error that crept in while I was simplifying the code for the question. As you can see from the output (which is cut & paste) it's definitely the same socket

Comment: From the `gdb` trace it looks like a race in the Ruby interpreter itself.

Comment: I agree. I was half expecting an answer along the lines of "Yes, IO#read does not respect the flags set on the underlying file descriptor." Maybe that's the intended behaviour but if so it should be documented because it's definitely not what one would expect. Thanks for looking anyway Nikolai.

Comment: One more thing - since that stack shows threads dispath - do you have multiple threads there? Other threads acessing the same socket by any chance?

Comment: No, I'm not using threads at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were right to expect the answer "IO#read does not respect the flags set on the underlying file descriptor":

[ruby 1.9.3 IO#read](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-read)

> Note that this method behaves like fread() function in C. If you need
>   the behavior like read(2) system call, consider readpartial,
>   read_nonblock and sysread.

I appreciate that you're using 1.8, but

- you're seeing the process stuck in `io_fread`, and
- `IO#read_nonblock` is available in 1.8 as well.